# Mongo charts managing via CI/CD

Tags: mongodb, charts, config, cicd

Is there a way to manage mongo charts via git repo and CI/CD tools?
I mean storing charts config somewhere and get them created automaticaly after running CD pipelines. I am looking for some analog of changelog for liquibase.
I just do not want to create my charts by hands on each environment. I prefer to make their creation/update via deployment process.

Comment: I don't think this is a `git` question.

Comment: removed tag, thanks